# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, syntax-error

Why is my website generating this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_VARIABLE

This is the code being executed:

```
public function __construct($name, $path = false, $options = false)
{    
    if ($path !== false)
    {
        static::configure('cache_directory');
    }    
    if ($options == true)
    {
        $name .= '-'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    $this->file_path = static::configure('cache_directory') .'/'. $name . '.idx.php';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That's hebrew for "double colon".

`static::configure` is likely what's causing problems. static is a PHP keyword - I doubt you can use it as a class name. If you're trying to use [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), make sure you've got PHP 5.3 or higher...